# Sinatra app as rack middleware TimesOut Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra, rack, middleware, geoip

While in the Rails development environment, I am attempting to add a Sinatra app as a middleware. The Sinatra app uses the [geoip gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/geoip) that processes a user's ip address and returns json with their city.

I can view the returned json by going directly to the example url in the browser or using curl in the command line, `http://local.fqdn.org/geoip/locate.json?ip=24.18.211.123`. However when I attempt to call the url with wget from within a Rails controller, the Rails app stops responding often crashing my browser and my rails server wont exit using the control+C command.

Any clue to what is happening here? Why would going directly to the url in the browser return the proper response but my call in the controller results in a Time Out?

**sinatra-geoip.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'geoip'
require 'json'

# http://localhost/geoip/locate.json?ip=24.18.211.123
#
# {
#     latitude: 47.684700012207
#     country_name: "United States"
#     area_code: 206
#     city: "Seattle"
#     region: "WA"
#     longitude: -122.384803771973
#     postal_code: "98117"
#     country_code3: "USA"
#     country_code: "US"
#     dma_code: 819
# }

class GeoIPServer < Sinatra::Base
    get '/geoip/locate.json' do
        c = GeoIP.new('/var/www/mywebsite.org/current/GeoLiteCity.dat').city(params[:ip])
        body c.to_h.to_json
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
mount GeoIPServer => "/geoip"
```

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
Website::Application.configure do
    require "sinatra-geoip"
    config.middleware.use "GeoIPServer"

...
end
```

**controller**

```
raw_geo_ip = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://#{geoip_server}/geoip/locate.json?ip=#{request.ip}"))
@geo_ip = JSON.parse(raw_geo_ip)
```

Answer (score 1):

Our solution was difficult to find. We ended up finding a method in the sinatra source code call `forward`.

**new sinatra-geoip.rb**

```
class GeoIPServer < Sinatra::Base
    if defined?(::Rails)
        get '/properties.json' do
            env["geo_ip.lookup"] = geo_ip_lookup(request.ip)
            forward
        end
    end

    def geo_ip_lookup(ip = nil)
        ip = ip.nil? ? params[:ip] : ip
        result = GeoIP.new('/var/www/mywebsite.org/current/GeoLiteCity.dat').city(ip)
        result.to_h.to_json
    end
end
```

Essentially, we removed the `/geoip/locate.json` route from the file and converted it to a simple method. We needed the geoip lookup to occur when the `properties.json` was being called, so a new param was added with the geoip information. Then we set the new param equal to `@geo_ip` variable in the controller.

**New properties controller**

```
if Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?
    # Retrieves param set by sinatra-geoip middleware.
    @geo_ip = JSON.parse(env["geo_ip.lookup"] || "{}")
else
    # Production and staging code
end
```

Rather obscure problem and solution. Hopefully it will help someone out there. *Cheers.*